# GROUP BY query with extra column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation, string-concatenation

My SQL skills are rusty and despite Googling I can't quite figure out this one. I'll be thankful for any help.

I have an orders table, with typical order-related fields: order # (which is the primary key), purchase order #, etc.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is this: find duplicate PO numbers, and list the order numbers to wich they are related. The output should be something akin to this:

```
PO #   |   ORDERS
-----------------
1234   | qwerty, abc
-----------------
1235   | xyz, def
```

So far I've come up with a query that finds duplicate PO numbers and their occurrences, but I can't figure out the orders list part.

```
SELECT PO,COUNT(PO) AS OCCURRENCES
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY PO
HAVING COUNT(PO) > 1
```

BTW, this is Oracle, if it makes any difference (something I'm new to, in addition to my rusty skills, argh!). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic for the "more than one PO" is correct. If you want the order numbers for duplicated PO's to be in a comma-delimited list, the [`LISTAGG` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) will do the trick:

```
SELECT
  PO,
  LISTAGG(OrderNumber, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OrderNumber) AS OrderNums
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY PO
HAVING COUNT(PO) > 1
```

To view the documentation for LISTAGG [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT groups.orders FROM (SELECT PO,COUNT(PO) AS OCCURRENCES
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY PO
HAVING COUNT(PO) > 1) groups
JOIN orders on orders.po = groups.po
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I used Oracle, but, I think this will do the trick:

```
SELECT PO,
       OCCURENCES,
       ORDERID /* not sure about your column name for order # */
  FROM ORDERS
 WHERE PO IN
       (
           SELECT PO
            FROM ORDERS
        GROUP BY PO
          HAVING COUNT(PO) > 1
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wm_concat` function:

```
select
  PO,
  wm_concat(OrderNumber) AS ORDERS
from orders
group by PO
having count(PO) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works, too. I wondered what was the difference between LISTAGG and WM_CONCAT, so I googled and it seems WM_CONCAT is not supported by Oracle [link](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm)

Comment: Yes, but it works! :) it makes for less code, which I prefer.